# Flutter - How to convert Image to List<Int>?

Tags: flutter

I want to make the following code work and I do not understand image conversion properly. Would really like someone to point me the right direction to learn this please along with providing a solution to my following problem.

I display the image as a container background image using:

> MemoryImage(base64Decode(image)) // My image is in base64 String format here

The above works fine.

Now I have an image path: example-

> '/data/user/0/....../cache/scaled_image_picker2751194612758734223.jpg'

How do I go from getting image from this path to base64Encode(image)?

I tried the following up to now and have run out of ideas here:

```
final Image? image = await Image.file(File(_imagePath));
    if (image != null){
      setState(() => imageDisplayInContainer = base64Encode(image)); <----Doesn't work
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the file object:

```
File imageFile = File(_imagePath);
```

Get the bytes:

```
List<int> imageBytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
```

Give the bytes the MemoryImage

```
MemoryImage(imageBytes);
```